# Partition with two predicate

Tags: loops, rust

I am looking for a way to partition a `Vec` with two predicate :

- One for the first partition point. For example x > 3
- One for the last element of the partition. For example x < 7

And so for example this vector :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

having this slice :

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

I think I can use `partition_point` twice like the [example on std](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.partition_point). But is there another method (or crate) where I can pass directly two predicate and slice between the first match of the first predicate and the first match of the second predicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that slice actually fulfills this partitioning, your best bet is to use the double `partition_point` approach.

```rust
fn partition_twice_slice<T>(
    vs: &[T],
    start_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
    end_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
) -> &[T] {
    let start = vs.partition_point(start_pred);
    let end = start + vs[start..].partition_point(end_pred);
    &vs[start..end]
}
```

If you just need the first slice that fulfills the partitioning requirements, you can get more creative.

On iterators you can use [`skip_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) and [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while):

```rust
fn partition_twice_iter<T>(
    vs: Vec<T>,
    start_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
    end_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
) -> Vec<T> {
    vs.into_iter()
        .skip_while(|el| start_pred(el))
        .take_while(|el| end_pred(el))
        .collect()
}
```

If you only need the slice, you can adapt this to find the bound indices:

```rust
fn partition_twice_slice<T>(
    vs: &[T],
    start_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
    end_pred: impl Fn(&T) -> bool,
) -> &[T] {
    let start = (0..vs.len())
        .find(|&i| start_pred(&vs[i]))
        .unwrap_or(vs.len());
    let end = (start..vs.len())
        .find(|&i| !end_pred(&vs[i]))
        .unwrap_or(vs.len());
    &vs[start..end]
}
```

Example usage:

```rust
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        partition_twice_iter(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], |&x| x <= 3, |&x| x < 7),
        vec![4, 5, 6]
    );
    assert_eq!(
        partition_twice_slice(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], |&x| x <= 3, |&x| x < 7),
        &[4, 5, 6]
    );
}
```

Note that I turned around your `x > 3` requirement to better fit the convention of `partition_point`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty trivial to implement yourself.  It's just a function that takes a slice and two predicates, and returns a subslice:

```
fn partition<T, P1, P2>(i: &[T], mut p1: P1, mut p2: P2) -> &[T]
    where P1: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
          P2: FnMut(&T) -> bool
{
    let mut start: usize = 0;

    while start < i.len() && !p1(&i[start]) {
        start += 1;
    }

    let mut end = start;

    while end < i.len() && p2(&i[end]) {
        end += 1;
    }

    &i[start..end]
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfd9ef0383995760a9405c2423b19b03))